# jquery ajax - fired event on remote machine is aborting after 1 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout, abort

I`d like to fire an event on the localhost machine and on a remote machine. The event is an import from a XML into a SQL-DB.
The import needs about 5secs. The problem now is that the import runs well on the localhost machine but not on the remote machine. If the import was fired at the remote machine ON the remote machine, it runs also well. 
In the FF-Webdevoloper-tool, I can see that the event on the local machine is wasting about 5 secs and the event on the remote machine is wasting 1 sec.
The result is, that not the whole XML was imported in the DB. I guess that the import wastes to much time, which occurs in an abortion of the import procedure by the jquery ajax function. Any ideas how to solve this?

Here is my code of the function:

```
function Zurueck(){
// fired event on localhost
   $.ajax({
        url: "zurueck.php",
         data: {encoder : encoderID,  tabelle: Tabelle},
        datatype: "json",
   type: "POST",
        success: function(data) { 
 }
   });

// same fired event on remote machine
   $.ajax({
   // pfad zur PHP Datei (ab HTML Datei)
        url: "http://192.168.2.151/backend/zurueck.php",
         data: {encoder : encoderID,  tabelle: Tabelle},
         dataType: "json", 
   type: "POST",
        success: function(data) { 
 }
   });   
}
```

and here is the code of the local and remote procedure:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('TEST.XML'); 
//.....
// do something, and so on 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is really problem with script being cancelled by browser then you could try [ignnore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) php function.

But I think you should check if there is no other problem on server side that stops import. Maybe it just fails quietly on some error like out of memory or it is configured to only give 5 secs for script (would be strange, non-standard, but could happen - look on max_execution_time in php.ini or phpinfo() result).

Comment: max_execution_time is 120sec, that should not be the problem.
On server side, there is no problem. The script runs well if it is executed without the jquery axaj call. I`ll try the php ignore.